# what Assassin's Creed 2 Patch version?

Tags: pc, assassins-creed-2

I just wanted some Information and maybe someone smart enough to get me the solution.When I run the patch it show an error message "this patch is designed for version 1.00. 1.01 was found instead". What does this thing really means I am talking about the version? What is this version of? and how can i overcome this problem. Any answers?

Comment: "1.01 was found instead" is referring to your current game version (latest patch). Meaning you are trying to update with an older patch.

Answer (score 1):

As Ben pointed out, you are trying to patch v1.00 but you already have updated to v1.01.
Try updating to future versions. I think the latest version for AC2 is v1.06. uPlay should automatically try and update your game, or you can manually get the update from ubisoft or google for it.